# Pattern matching a list with conditionals

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a list of integers:

```
val l = List(100, 200, 100)
```

I am trying to pattern match on its values, but the rules are a little complicated.

```
1. 100 or 200, but at least 1 100 
2. 300 or 400, with at least 1 300 and the rest 300 or 400
3. 700 or 800, with at least 1 700 and the rest 700 or 800
```

Is it possible to express this in a pattern match expression?

```
val result: Option[String] = l match {
 case (100 | 200) ???  => "1"
 case (300 | 400) ??? => "2"
 case (700 | 800) ??? => "3"
 case _ => None
}
```

Comment: what happens to values that don't match? Like `List(200,200)` (i.e. does not contain `100`) ?

Comment: And returning "1" in one branch and None on the other doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid doing an exhaustive check for each case `O(n^2)`, first take the minimum element of the list `O(n)` to discriminate the case, and validate that the list has only the expected elements (O(n)). This should work:

```
val result:Option[Int] = (l.min, l) match {
  case (100, l) if l.forall(Set(100,200)) => Some(1)
  case (300, l) if l.forall(Set(300,400)) => Some(2)
  case (700, l) if l.forall(Set(700,800)) => Some(3)
  case _ => None
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the logic you're looking for?  It's a bit hard to tell from your description.

```
val result: Option[String] = lst match {
  case 100 :: _ => Some("1")
  case 200 :: t if t contains 100 => Some("1")

  case 300 :: _ if lst.forall(x => x==300 || x==400)
           => Some("2")
  case 400 :: t if lst.contains(300) && lst.forall(x => x==300 || x==400)
           => Some("2")
  case 700 :: _ if lst.forall(x => x==700 || x==800)
           => Some("3")
  case 800 :: t if lst.contains(700) && lst.forall(x => x==700 || x==800)
           => Some("3")
  case _ => None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really match on the values like that. You can do something like this though:

```
l match {
  case _ if l.forall(Set(100,200).contains) && l.contains(100) => Some("1")
  case _ if l.forall(Set(300,400).contains) && l.contains(300) => Some("2")
  case _ if l.forall(Set(700,800).contains) && l.contains(700) => Some("3")
  case _ => None
}
```

Not the most efficient though, as you're traversing the list twice for each case. It can be done more efficiently with some form of `foldLeft`.